subsets of $\{1,2,...,2n\}$ s.t it does not contain $a,b$ that $|a-b|=n.$

Let $n$ be a positive integer. How many subsets of $\{1,2,...,2n\}$
s.t it does not contain $a,b$ that $|a-b|=n.$

Here is the list of all the pairs $(a,b)$ s.t $|a-b|=n$
$$(1,n+1), (2,n+2),...,(n,2n)$$
If we take $1$, we cannot take $n+1$.
If we take $n+1$, we cannot take $1$.
Or we can neither take $1$ nor $n+1$.
I don't know how to continue. Any help I would be very appreciated.

Please edit to include your efforts. A natural start might be to solve the problem for small $n$ and to look for patterns.  Alternatively (or in parallel), try to establish a recurrence.

I already included my thought on this problem!

Great job, you got the crux of the problem! To finish, for each pair you have $3$ choices as you described. Hence, by the multiplicative principle there are $3^n$ possible ways to construct such a subset.

When $n=2,$ then you would have $8$ distinct options, no?

${1},{2},{3},{4},{1,2},{1,4},{3,2},{3,4}$

and ${}{}{}{}$

@Empy2 I see. Good point
